# Running a "Select * From tableName" query using MySQL/OTP, with no 'WHERE'

Tags: mysql, erlang, erlang-otp

[This Driver](https://github.com/mysql-otp/mysql-otp) lets you call a mysql database within an Erlang program.

They provide an example for "Multiple Query and Multiple Result sets"

```
{ok, [{[<<"foo">>], [[42]]}, {[<<"bar">>], [[<<"baz">>]]}]} =
    mysql:query(Pid, "SELECT 42 AS foo; SELECT 'baz' AS bar;"),
```

But don't really really explain it, or show how to use it without the `AS`

---

I would like to execute a query like

```
{ok, [{[<<Latitude>>, [Longitude], [Image], [Username], [Bio]} = mysql:query(Db, "SELECT * FROM users",[])
```

This is my regular `select * from users`

mysql> select * from users;

```
+----------+-----------+-------+----------+-----------+
| latitude | longitude | image | username | bio       |
+----------+-----------+-------+----------+-----------+
| 44       | 44        |    45 | Sally    | Hello     |
| 42       | 43        |     0 | Bryce    | I'm me    |
| 20       | 24        |     0 | Richard  | I'm Great |
| 44       | 45        |     0 | Liz      | Yeah      |
+----------+-----------+-------+----------+-----------+
```

So I would want the first column stored within the variable Latitude, the second column stored in Longitude .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the library's example:

```
%% Select
{ok, ColumnNames, Rows} =
    mysql:query(Pid, <<"SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = ?">>, [1]),
```

You should be able to do it with the following query, with only [2 params on the query function call](https://github.com/mysql-otp/mysql-otp/blob/master/src/mysql.erl#L177):

```
{ok, [<<"latitude">>, <<"longitude">>, <<"image">>, <<"username">>, <<"bio">>], Rows} 
    = mysql:query(Pid, <<"SELECT * FROM users">>),
```

Where `Rows` would be like this (based on the table you posted):

```
[ 
    [44, 44, 45,<<"Sally">>, <<"Hello">>],
    [42, 43, 0,<<"Bryce">>, <<"I'm me">>],
    [20, 24, 0,<<"Richard">>, <<"Hello">>],
    [44, 45, 0,<<"Liz">>, <<"Yeah">>]
]
```

Each list item in the above structure is  a row from your DB table, field values in the same order as your select would request it (as you can see it from the `ColumnNames` list). You can use this list to transform it to whatever other structure you may need.